# Sitecore Content Hub Azure Active Directory Login

Tags: identity-server, azure-ad, content-hub

I am trying to implement `Azure AD` in my `Content Hub portal`. I have created the App in Azure Active Directory and also add the `Application ID URI`, `federation metadata` & `get the Entity Id`.

In my Content Hub portal, I have updated the `ExternalAuthenticationProviders.saml` and saved the same.

```
"ExternalAuthenticationProviders": {
    "global_username_claim_type": "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/name",
    "global_email_claim_type": "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/emailaddress",
    "saml": [
      {
        "metadata_location": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/<id>/federationmetadata/2007-06/federationmetadata.xml",
        "sp_entity_id": "api://<id>",
        "idp_entity_id": "https://sts.windows.net/<id>/",
        "password": null,
        "certificate": null,
        "binding": "HttpRedirect",
        "authn_request_protocol_binding": null,
        "is_enabled": true,
        "provider_name": "SamlNewLocal",
        "messages": {
          "signIn": "Azure AD",
          "signInDescription": "Azure AD",
          "signInTitle": "Azure AD"
        },
        "authentication_mode": "Active"
      }  
    ]
  }
```

After this, I can do the login using the admin (my own email id) successfully. **But the problem is I am not able to log in with other users.**

**Getting the below error from Content Hub:**
[image]

Need your help on this, I have also enabled `EnableRegister` to true for new users. The domain I am using is `user@<my domain>.onmicrosoft.com` (Free AD).

Can anyone please highlight any point or any configuration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To enable the Microsoft login, you just need the client id & secret. And put the follwing json settings in ExternalAuthenticationProviders.

```
"microsoft": [
      {
        "authentication_mode": "Passive",
        **"client_id": "<client id>",**
        **"client_secret": "<client secret>",**
        "email_claim_type": "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/emailaddress",
        "external_user_creation_url": "",
        "is_enabled": true,
        "messages": {
          "signIn": "Microsoft Sign In",
          "signInDescription": "",
          "signInTitle": "Microsoft Sign In"
        },
        "provider_name": "Microsoft",
        "username_claim_type": "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/name",
      }
    ]
```

And make sure the AutoCreateUsers & EnableCredentialless is true.

Answer (score -1):

To log in with the other user you need to perform the below steps:

1. Create Groups into Azure AD like Author, Editor, or a single group like you have created Admin Group in your Azure AD. It will give you a unique GUID. Assign that group to all those users, which you want to log in.
2. Next, you need to create the same group as a Role into the Sitecore and assign that role to the users.
3. Now you need to map the claims between both Azure Group Id and Sitecore Role into your `Sitecore.Plugin.IdentityProvider.AzureAd.xml` file. You can find this file from location: `{root path}\{your SC Identity Server Instance name}\Config\production`

**Find sample code below:** I have created `Approver Group` on AD which Id is `14e9c831-bb83-4870-gh29-60b3354b215e` and Role into the Sitecore named 'sitecore\Approver'.

```
<AzureADUserToApprover type="Sitecore.Plugin.IdentityProviders.DefaultClaimsTransformation, Sitecore.Plugin.IdentityProviders">
              <SourceClaims>               
                <Claim1 type="groups" value="14e9c831-bb83-4870-gh29-60b3354b215e" />                
              </SourceClaims>
              <NewClaims>
                <Claim1 type="role" value="sitecore\Approver" />
              </NewClaims>
            </AzureADUserToApprover>
```

For more details, see the blog post: [Setting Up Azure Active Directory Integration with Sitecore Identity Server](https://sitecore.derekc.net/setting-up-azure-active-directory-integration-with-sitecore-identity-server-sitecore-9-1/)

Comment: Hi Himmat, thanks for sharing this but my ask is for Sitecore Content Hub. Not Sitecore XP or XM